# jQuery - Keep click event within ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a script that when a button is clicked, will check by ajax if the user is logged in, and if so, do some actions without leaving the page. If the user is not logged in, I want to open a login window popup. THe problem is that since window.open() is not directly under the 'click' event, it gets blocked by popup blockers. If I put the window.open right under the click action, it works fine.

Any way around this?

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
        $.get(ajaxUrl, function(hastoken) {
            if(hastoken == 1) {
                // do stuff here                        
            } else {

                window.open("http://www.google.com");
                // login
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: The solution is simple. Don't work with popup windows. Use things like [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: :) Great solution, but I need to load an external URL (login is through instagram account)

Comment: You could use an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using fancybox: ( http://fancybox.net/ )

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    $.get(ajaxUrl, function(hastoken) {
        if(hastoken == 1) {
            // do stuff here                        
        } else {

           $("#some_div").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
       });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, Here's what I came up with, many thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2592780/249868). Basically, I wrapped the ajax call in a synchronous wrapper, keeping the windw.open in the right level.

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    var hasToken = getResponse(url);
    if(hastoken == 1) {
        // do stuff here                        
    } else {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
        // login
    }
});


function getResponse(strUrl) {
  var strReturn = "";

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: strUrl,
    success: function(html) {
      strReturn = html;
    },
    async:false
  });

  return strReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you- this will open a kind of light box...

```
 $('.myButton').click(function() {
            $.get(ajaxUrl, function(hastoken) {
                if(hastoken == 1) {
                    // do stuff here                        
                } else {

                    var dialogDiv=$("<div></div>");                               
            var $dialog = $(dialogDiv)
            .load("Your Url to login form")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "Message Box",
                width: 900,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function() {                    
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $dialog.dialog("open");

            return false;
        }

                }
            }); 
        });
```